# Firemonkey TButton style with two different texts

Tags: delphi, button, firemonkey, firemonkey-style

I'm trying to create a virtual keypad, where each button has both a number and a few letters. For example, the number `2` will also have the text `ABC` next to it, in a smaller font size, and the number `3` will have `DEF` next to it.

I can successfully edit the custom style of these buttons one by one. A single button, I can drop a `TText` style element, change the alignment and text settings of each, and it works fine...

[image: Designing button style]

However, I have to do this one by one, customizing the style of each button by itself. If I try to re-use this style, the extra letters `ABC` will be the same on all keys. But I need them each to be different.

[image: Sample of keypad in runtime]

How can I make a single re-usable style which can also allow me to use varying sub-text in each button? Or will I have to create a unique style for each button?

Comment: I had to do something similar and at the end I created a custom style for each. Not the best idea but it worked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do a workaround, set text `StyleName` of ABC Label to text and the StyleName of Number Label to Number.

Create a class that overrides the button class.

```
TButton = class(FMX.StdCtrls.TButton)
protected
  procedure ApplyStyle; override;
end;

procedure TButton.ApplyStyle;
  var NumberLabel : TLabel;
begin
  //That method will find for a label with stylename number and set the tag of component in it.
  inherited;
  if FindStyleResource<TLabel>('Number', NumberLabel) then
    NumberLabel.Text := IntToStr(Tag);
end;
```

Now set the style for all buttons. Text property will set text alphanumeric text and tag will set the Number. It will work only in runtime.